# How to alter a view with SCHEMABINDING when other views are dependent on it

Tags: t-sql, view, schemabinding

We have views created with `SCHEMABINDING` and they are used in other views that also have `SCHEMABINDING`

I want to alter the base view to include newly added columns of the table but it is not allowing to alter it saying that other views are dependent of this view.

Can we alter view without schemabinding and after change later alter it again to apply schemabinding?

Does it work like that?

Comment: Why don't you give it a try on a test environment? :) However, take a look at the documentation remarks: [Altering the view will drop all indexes on that view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/ms173846(v=sql.110)#remarks).

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/1942/6171